# match coordinates and projection of a raster layer and shapefile in R

Tags: r, coordinates, transform, geospatial, raster

I have two spatial objects that I'm working with - a raster layer and a shapefile of my study region. I'm trying to crop my raster to my shapefile, but I'm having trouble getting the coordinate systems to match.

Here is a summary of my spatial objects:

Raster Layer

```
> testxx
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 450, 3245, 1460250  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.1109257, 0.3826826  (x, y)
extent     : -179.9964, 179.9576, -89.98608, 82.22108  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 5.389717e-06, 0.0002052335  (min, max)
```

Shapefile

```
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 1 
extent      : 5951759, 7591708, 649338.9, 2306575  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
variables   : 8
names       : PRUID,  PRNAME, PRENAME, PRFNAME, PREABBR, PRFABBR, BUFF_DIST, ORIG_FID 
value       :    35, Ontario, Ontario, Ontario,    Ont.,    Ont.,     10000,        5
```

This is the code I tried:

```
# Add a coordinate system to the raster
crs(testxx) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"

# change shapefile coordinate system 
aoi <- spTransform(on_shp, crs(testxx))
```

But the coordinates themselves still don't match - the shapefile is still in meters, while the raster is in lat and long.

Thanks!

Comment: Your rasterfile probably does not have WSG1984 coordinates. So you add the wrong crs. Try to figure out the right one (maybe its Lambert Conformal Conic since its often used in canada). Plot your raster to see if it makes sense. Then use spTransform().

Answer (score 0):

The coordinate reference system for the SpatialPolygonsDataFrame is clearly wrong. Given this `extent`:

```
extent      : 5951759, 7591708, 649338.9, 2306575  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
```

It cannot be

```
crs         : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
```

So you need to find out what it actually is. To test whether it is correct you could set it to what you think it is and then transform to lon/lat and see if ends up in the right place.